# Kafka Streams - How to do global metric aggregations?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So I need to have a `GlobalKTable` containing the aggregation of several messages across many instances. Right now, my single instance `KTable` setup looks something like this:

```java
final KTable<String, Double> aggregatedMetrics = eventStream
        .groupByKey(Serdes.String(), jsonSerde)
        .aggregate(
                () -> 0d,
                new MetricsAggregator(),
                Serdes.Double(),
                LOCAL_METRICS_STORE_NAME);
```

Obviously, this doesn't scale since each instance only has the updated metrics for the messages it has received, not for all of the messages received by all the other instances. I was thinking of using this:

```java
final KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();   
builder.globalTable(METRIC_CHANGES_TOPIC, METRICS_STORE_NAME);
```

and then just streaming updates to my `aggregatedMetrics` KTable to the `METRIC_CHANGES_TOPIC`, which would update the global table. However, each instance would just be overwriting the other instances' aggregations on each update to the global table.

Is there any way I can do a global aggregation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution sound correct to me.

This does not sound correct:

> However, each instance would just be overwriting the other instances' aggregations on each update to the global table.

Note, that aggregations are done key-based. Thus, different instances will aggregate on different keys, and thus, each instance will just update its own keys in the `GlobalKTable`.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give me a link to documentation somewhere that discusses this in more detail?

Comment: Hope this helps: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/architecture.html